# Use comparison test to show $\sum\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to manipulate it such that $\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}\leq x^n$ for some $x<1$

Answer (score 3):

Notice

$$ \frac{ 3^n + 7^n }{3^n + 8^n} \leq\frac{3^n+7^n}{8^n} = \left( \frac{3}{8} \right)^n + \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^n $$

Should I say more?

Answer (score 0):

We have that eventually

$$\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}\leq \frac{(7.5)^n}{8^n}=\left(\frac{7.5}{8}\right)^n$$

as an alternative by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{7^n}{8^n}$ indeed

$$\frac{\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}}{\frac{7^n}{8^n}}=\frac{8^n(3^n+7^n)}{7^n(3^n+8^n)} \to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is often much easier and quicker to show $|a_n| \leq C\cdot x^n$ with a positive constant $C$.

In your case:
$$\color{blue}{\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}} = \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^n\frac{\left( \frac{3}{7} \right)^n + 1}{\left( \frac{3}{8} \right)^n + 1} \color{blue}{<} \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^n \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{2} + 1}{1} =\color{blue}{\frac{3}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^n}$$